editing ggcorrplot.mixed graph
I want to design my correlation plot similar to Fig 1 or Fig 2
Fig1. correlation plot1
Fig2. correlation plot2
However, when I use the following code, I am unable to recreate the styles shown in Fig1 or 2:
ggcorrplot.mixed(corr, upper = "ellipse", lower = "number", p.mat = p.mat, 
                 insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))

This is what my current plot looks like:
Fig3. correlation plot3
How can I modify the code so that the numbers in the plot appear in black, similar to Fig1 or 2???

Hello, welcome to SO. Can you post some of your data and code to create the models? This will make it much easier to reproduce the issue and see what's going on. You could copy-paste the output of dput(head(data, 20)) into your question. Also, please use markdown to format your posts. Specifically, you can render figures in markdown using ![figure title](https://static_address/image.png).

The color is hard-coded into the ggcorrplot.mixed function so it cannot be modified easily. And adding "col=1" would change everything to black, including the ellipses.
I looked at the code for this function. You can get around this issue by melting the correlation matrix and adding your own geom_text() call afterwards.
p <- ggcorrplot.mixed(corr, upper = "ellipse", lower = "number", p.mat = p.mat, insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))

library(dplyr)

corr2 <- reshape2::melt(corr, value.name = "rho") |>
  mutate(rid = as.integer(as.factor(.data$Var1)), cid = as.integer(as.factor(.data$Var2))) %>% 
  mutate(part = case_when(.$rid < .$cid ~ "upper", .$rid == .$cid ~ "diag", .$rid > .$cid ~ "lower")) |>
  mutate(abs.rho = abs(.data$rho)) |> 
  mutate(rho.label = ifelse(.data$rho == 1, .data$rho, format(round(.data$rho, digits = 2), nsmall = 2)))

lower.dat <- corr2 |> filter(part == "lower")

p + geom_text(data = lower.dat, mapping = aes(x = cid, y = rid, colour = 1, label = rho.label))



library(psych)
ct <- corr.test(mtcars, adjust = "none")
corr <- ct$r

